# Stack Overflow judgement of question quality is too open

Tags: feature-request, question-quality

It takes three votes to close a question. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561944/how-to-configure-a-uinavigationbar-depending-on-where-it-is) is about to close but it is a perfectly valid question.

Have I posted in the wrong place? Should the feature be tightened up so that it's more than 3 votes?

Or is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561944/how-to-configure-a-uinavigationbar-depending-on-where-it-is) an inappropriate question for Stack Overflow? Is there a service on this network for questions regarding refactoring or questions regarding 'how would you implement this instead'?

Comment: _"It takes three..."_ Nope, Five.

Comment: I have no clue about your question, but I'm pretty sure we are not closing too many questions.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: "but it is a perfectly valid question" - I'd argue that the question *asker* is almost never the best judge of the quality of a question.

Comment: Maybe you can justify/clarify your statement of *"judgement of question quality is too open"* a bit more? That seems to have little to do with the actual body of your thesis.

Comment: But it is a valid question. Until someone posts something, like a comment, suggesting otherwise, then I'm afraid I can't accept that the question is invalid. I'm not asking a philosophical question or a hypothesis about space/time. It's not difficult to see that it's a valid question. In regards to the  question here on Meta: it is more focused more on highlighting the issue rather than suggesting a solution. I don't have a solution at the moment. I certainly didn't suggest that the person asking the question be the person that judges it's quality.

Comment: "But it is a valid question. Until someone posts something, like a comment, suggesting otherwise, then I'm afraid I can't accept that the question is invalid." People have cast downvotes and close votes, equivalent to comments with text corresponding to the option they voted for.

Comment: You are asking too many questions within your question. Some people are addressing the  `feature-request` part of your question (_Should the feature be tightened up so that it's more than 3 votes?_, following on your _judgement of question quality_ title.) Some people are addressing your concern about your question on main being on-topic or not. Not many are agreeing with either view, and IMO no one can recommend you a site to go within SE with that specific question.

Comment: Down voting without a comment is tricky though right? What is stopping my mother logging in and down voting this stuff? An expert opinion as to why it is worthy of a down vote would give the system more validity, no?

Comment: I disagree. @cerbrus has been a great service to this thread. Cerburus has provided an answer to which I accepted and a lot of feedback in comments.

Comment: You disagree with what?

Comment: You. "You are asking too many questions within your question..."

Comment: That's up to you. Whatever you think, you did ask more than one question. Cerbrus chose to answer one of those, and I agree with his answer. But that doesn't mean there aren't more questions in your question. What about your feature request? What about your site recommendation? And now you added even more bits about downvotes... But if you can't see that, I'm afraid I can't do much for you. Good luck out there!

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to need it.

Comment: If your mother earns 125 rep here then nothing else will stop her from downvoting. Do you think she will be able to do that? If so she's just as welcome as everyone else.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know (or rather failed to remember) a need to 125 is required for down voting. To answer you question: I think she could. I have seen people get upvotes for comments like 'I like this' or 'this is the best answer'.

Comment: No rep is earned for comment upvotes, she'd have to try harder than that.

Comment: That's comforting

Comment: The trouble is you're not really interested in listening to the rest of us. You think your question is great and no amount of telling you it isn't will change your mind. The closure message tells you what's wrong with it.

Comment: No one has told me (with a comment) what is wrong with the question. So how can you say that? Regarding the question here, I have accepted an answer and given thanks!

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.
If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.

Comment: I see it now but it wasn't there a moment ago Robert. Timestamps are you friend.

Comment: It's not been closed that long.

Comment: Suggesting I might not have seen it.

Comment: So the moral of the story is: as votes continue to drop a question below a certain threshold, a moderator or administrative person of some kind will step in an eventually close a question with a comment explaining why it was bad. *Roughly around the time I kick up a stink about it for 20 minutes.

Comment: No, that's not how it works at all.

Comment: No moderators or admins closed your question, nor was it closed because it dropped below a threshold. What you did was post on meta (where lots of high rep users hang out) saying go look at this question. We did, we decided it should be closed according to the rules of this site when we looked at it, so we closed it.

Comment: I posted here and go an emotionally charged comment like "The trouble is you're not really interested in listening to the rest of us.", which was totally out of order. I simply didn't see that you closed it. All I have been suggesting in this thread, is if the downvotes, leading up to the final decision, had some indication as to why they were being placed, during the time they were being cast, then it might have been more transparent and more comforting and informative.

Comment: Maybe you should read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s).

Comment: And the indication is already there. What you need to do, is every time you get a down vote imagine that you got an anonymous comment, saying precisely what the down-vote hover-text says.

Comment: @yivi that's a great thread. reading it now. spot on the point I'm trying to make here. thanks for being a gent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question boils down to:

> *"What is the best way to do X"*

Those questions *are* Primarily Opinion Based, and as such a poor fit for Stack Overflow.

As the POB close-vote reason states:

> *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.*

Comment: That's a great answer. Suggesting this is a valid question to ask. Yet if you take a look at the question now, it has been down voted 3 times at time of writing. Further, since positing this question only moments ago, the question I reference on stack overflow has been voted for closure twice more.

Comment: @robdashnash: By posting about your question on Meta, you're drawing more attention to said question. That's called the ["Meta Effect"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect). that extra attention _can_ come with votes, as more people see it.

Comment: Right...So why is it being downvoted? It's a valid question no? It must be valid because you have given a great answer. So...why is it being down voted?

Comment: Oh, you mean this meta question. [Voting on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) is a little different than voting on the main site. Votes on meta are also used to express (dis)agreement with the general premise of a question. Your question also has a incorrect assumption (the 3 votes line), which doesn't help. Don't worry about votes here, though. They won't affect your reputation.

Comment: @robdashnash Also, since your question is a feature request, down votes on this meta question are used to express disagreement with the feature you are requesting.

Comment: Got it. Now I understand (in regards to how voting works here at meta). Thank you.

Comment: Is there a service on stack exchange for more opinion based question / answers? Such as, how would you refactor this?

Comment: Not really, @robdashnash. It might be a fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but before you ask there, have a very good look at their [Help Center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to give your question the best chance of being answered. Try to make it less opinionated, more factual...